# issue in many to many relationship entity framework code first method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have created an application in entityframework using  code first method.

In application , there are two entities which have many to many relationship between them.

```
public class Course
    {

        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Student> Student{ get; set; }
    }


   public class Student
    {

        [Key]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Course> Course{ get; set; }
    }
```

when I execute the project, it creates student table,Course table,StudentCourse table.

Now now the problem is,in StudentCourse table there are only two keys, StudentID and CourseId
I want to add additional column in that table how to do that ?

Comment: To be clear: You want a many-to-many relationship using a join table with columns with extra information about the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class defining that table:

```
public class Course
{

    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Student{ get; set; }
}

public class Student
{

    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Course> Course{ get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    //More columns here
}
```